# Why the extents of GeoDataFrame and masked file are different?

Tags: python, geopandas, extents, rasterio, geodataframe

`vector` = some shape file, MultiPolygon in GeoDataFrame. File `crs` and vector `crs` are the same.

```py
vector.geometry
```

> 0    MULTIPOLYGON (((47.59780 -19.38530, 47.59330 -...
> Name: geometry, dtype: geometry

```py
extent = [vector.total_bounds[0], vector.total_bounds[2], vector.total_bounds[1], vector.total_bounds[3]]

with rio.open(URL) as file:
    crs = vector.crs
    arr, out_transform = mask(file, vector.geometry, crop=True)

shapes = rio.features.shapes(arr, transform=out_transform)
geometry = []
vals = []
for polygon, value in shapes:
    if value > 0:
        vals.append(value)
        geometry.append(shape(polygon))

gdf2 = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'vals': vals, 'geometry': geometry}, crs=crs)
```

Now, when I plot the masked raster and resulting GeoDataFrame, I expect grids to match each other, but the reality is somewhat different...

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,8))
arr[arr <= 0 ] = 'nan'
base = show(arr[0], extent=extent, ax=ax)
colorbar = base.get_images()[0]
fig.colorbar(colorbar, ax=ax)
vector.plot(facecolor='none', edgecolor='grey', ax=ax)

gdf2.iloc[:].plot(facecolor='none', edgecolor='red', ax=ax);
```

[image: Output]

I find, that the extents of GeoDataFrames are different for some reasons.

```py
print(vector.total_bounds)
print(gdf2.total_bounds)
```

> [ 46.495  -19.5584  48.037  -17.707 ]
> [ 46.744999 -19.540326  48.078327 -17.873666]

And this is despite the specified transform parameter:
`out_transform`

> Affine(0.083333, 0.0, 46.415761,
> 0.0, -0.083333, -17.666236000000012)

What do I do wrong?

Libraries imported:

```py
import numpy as np
import rasterio as rio
from rasterio.mask import mask
from rasterio.plot import show
from shapely.geometry import shape
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import geopandas as gpd
```

Comment: Taras, thanks for the edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a `transform` to `rasterio.plot.show`:

```
base = show(arr[0], extent=extent, ax=ax, transform=out_transform)
```

Reproducible example:

```py
import numpy as np
import rasterio as rio
from rasterio.mask import mask
from rasterio.plot import show
from shapely.geometry import shape
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import geopandas as gpd


# Some dummy data
url = "https://github.com/rasterio/rasterio/raw/main/tests/data/RGB2.byte.tif"
features = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "id": "0",
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {"id": 1},
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Polygon",
                "coordinates": [
                    [[238793, 2653121], [243276, 2656230], [249353, 2651980], [242146, 2649325], [238793, 2653121]]]
            }
        }
    ]
}

with rio.open(url) as raster:
    crs = raster.crs

    vector = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(features, crs)
    extent = [vector.total_bounds[0], vector.total_bounds[2], vector.total_bounds[1], vector.total_bounds[3]]

    arr, out_transform = mask(raster, vector.geometry, crop=True)

shapes = rio.features.shapes(arr, transform=out_transform)
geometry = []
vals = []
for polygon, value in shapes:
    if value > 0:
        vals.append(value)
        geometry.append(shape(polygon))

gdf2 = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'vals': vals, 'geometry': geometry}, crs=crs)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,8))
arr[arr <= 0 ] = 0  # replaced nan with 0 just to get the code
                    # to work with above byte data
base = show(arr[0], extent=extent, ax=ax, transform=out_transform)
colorbar = base.get_images()[0]
fig.colorbar(colorbar, ax=ax)
vector.plot(facecolor='none', edgecolor='grey', ax=ax)

gdf2.iloc[:].plot(facecolor='none', edgecolor='red', ax=ax);

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks for the response!